# Saving OneToOne to User with Update View

Tags: django

**models.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfile(Model):
    vendor_venue = BooleanField(default=False)
    info = CharField(max_length=250)

    user = OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile')
```

**views.py**

```
class OwnerProfileEdit(UpdateView):

    model = User
    form_class = UserForm
    success_message = 'Profilul a fost actualizat'

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return self.request.user

    .....

    def form_valid(self, form):
        profile_form = UserProfileForm(self.request.POST)
        if profile_form.is_valid():
            profile_form.save(commit=False)
            profile_form.user = self.request.user
            profile_form.save()
        return super(OwnerProfileEdit, self).form_valid(form)
```

**forms.py**

```
class UserProfileForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        exclude = ('vendor_venue', 'user')
```

This is the code for saving a User Profile with a OneToOneField relation to User.

When I'm trying to save the profile I get the error

```
(1048, "Column 'user_id' cannot be null")
```

Why is this happening? It shouldn't happen. What am I doing wrong? Thank you
I specify that if I simply use only UserForm, without UserProfileForm, everything works just fine

thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

You're saving the form in your view and adding the user, but then you're still calling the superclass form_valid, which does the same thing again, without your user.

Instead of doing that save, see [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#models-and-request-user) on how to set the user there.

**Edit** Sorry, I misread your question. The problem is actually that you need to set the user to the model instance returned by form.save, not on the form itself.

```
        profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
        profile.user = self.request.user
        profile.save()
```

Comment: Hi, Daniel. Yes, but I have to forms, `profile_form` which is for UserPRofile and `form` which is for User. I'm not setting the user twice for the same object. Right?

Comment: sorry for the typo: I have two forms*

Comment: I have a feeling that `profile.user = self.request.user` doesn't work properly because self.request.user is a SimpleLazyObject

Comment: What makes you think that? Did you try it? The lazy object is transformed into an actual user when you access it.

Comment: What to try? Just before doing profile.save(), here is what I have: ``(Pdb) profile_form.user``
``<SimpleLazyObject: <User: andi>>``

Comment: Geez, so stupid mistake...anyway, I was thinking wrong anyway, because I already have a profile and I get duplicate error. Because I am creating a Profile with a signal attached on User. Thanks anyway. Now I know how to fix my problem